# parenthesis after variable name is valid or not in C programming?

Tags: c, variables, declaration, variable-declaration

I just try to create variable with parenthesis "**n_()**" in **C** but it not work it's give me error. can some one tell me what the problem in it.
[image]

Comment: You can write the parentheses, but they convert the 'variable' into a (non-prototype) function declaration.  They'll never be part of an identifier in C.

Answer (score 4):

In C, `int n_();` declares a function returning `int`, not a variable. `()` is not, and cannot be, part of the identifier name.

Answer (score 1):

If you see the definition of an identifier in the standard, you get.

```
identiﬁer:
   identiﬁer-nondigit
   identiﬁer identiﬁer-nondigit
   identiﬁer digit

identiﬁer-nondigit:
   nondigit
   universal-character-name
   other implementation-deﬁned characters

 nondigit: one of
    _abcdefghijklm
    nopqrstuvwxyz
    ABCDEFGHIJKLM
    NOPQRSTUVWXYZ

digit: one of
    0123456789
```

An identifier can only start with the values in nondigit and have the values in nondigit and digit as elements

`abc, a1234, __abc, ab_c` are all valid identifiers.

`1abc, abc+, abc(, ab-c,`  are not valid identifiers.

P.S. a `universal-character-name` is defined as below

```
universal-character-name:
   \u hex-quad
   \U hex-quad hex-quad

hex-quad:
    hexadecimal-digit hexadecimal-digit
    hexadecimal-digit hexadecimal-digit
```

They are used to refer to characters not in the basic character set. e.g. \u0024 ($), \u0040 (@)